# Proof of $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have this messy proof of $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$ in my notebook. I can't find it anywhere else, but I need it since the professor accepts only this version at the exam. At the time I am only stuck with the first part, so I will write the proof only to that point. Also, there is a few steps with missing reasoning between them.

*Proof.*

We are given two sequences:

$$x_n=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$y_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

If $x_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=e$. *(This is given.)*

Let's prove that $x_n$ converges.

To prove that, the Monotone Convergence Theorem will be used.

Since $x_{n+1}>x_{n}$ the sequence is increasing. *(I skipped the unnecessary reasoning for this.)*

Now let's prove that it is bounded from above.

$$n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n>2^{n-1}\tag{1.1}$$
$$\frac{1}{n!}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\tag{1.2}$$

$$\underbrace{2}_{\text{?}}\leq x_n\leq 1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\tag{1.3}$$

$$1+q+q^2+\dots+q^{n-1}=\underbrace{\overbrace{\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}}^{?}=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}}_{\text{?}}\tag{1.4}$$

$$q=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\underbrace{1}_{\text{?}}+\frac{1-\frac{1}{q^n}}{1-\frac{1}{q}}=1+2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)<1+2=3\tag{1.5}$$

And so $2\leq x_n\leq3$, $x_n$ is bounded and increasing, hence it converges. Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=e$.

The proof proceeds with proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=Y$, and then showing $y\geq e$ and $y \leq e$, and thereby $y=e$. This part is very long and already looking messy in the notebook. Because of that I will skip it, since it isn't important for the question.

---

**My questions:**

1. Is there any obvious reason why $2^{n-1}$ is a good (necessary?) choice for the inequality (1.1)?
2. How does (1.2) follow from (1.1)? Why is it $\leq$ and not $ < $ ? I see that $\leq$ is the right choice since for $n=1$, we have $\frac{1}{1!}=\frac{1}{2^{1-1}}$, but is there any way to know this without evaluating for choices of $n$?
3. Why is that $2$ there in inequality (1.3)? Where did it come from ?
4. Considering inequality (1.4) there is few things;

   a) How was the overbraced fraction derived from the geometric series?

   b) The underbraced equality at first didn't make sense to me, but when I evaluated for few $n$s, I realized it actually holds. Is this a known thing, that the order of subracting isn't important for two fractions to be equal, as long as both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction are both $<0$ or $>0$? Also what was the role of the equality in the proof, or was it just a remark ?

   EDIT: I just realized that we can do that since the fraction is always positive. But it still doesn't seem so obvious to notice. Should it be obvious?
5. Why is that $1$ there in the inequality (1.5) ? Where did it come from ?
6. If you have a source for this proof please send me a link or tell me where I can find it.

Thanks

Comment: Several of your questions will be resolved by assuming that $n\ge2$.

Comment: $\le$ is a weaker condition.  $0 < a < b \implies \frac 1b < \frac 1a \implies \frac 1b \le \frac 1a$.

Comment: Um... you aren't asking anything about the *second* sequence and why the sequence would converge to the same thing.  Is that part okay?  that's *really* the more important issue.

Comment: @fleablood well, I still have to go through that part, since the proof in my notebook was barely readable, but I got the general idea how we get there. I will proceed with the proof in Rudin straight away. I will ask a new question if I get stuck there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1) we want

$x_n = 1 + \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} + ..... + \frac 1{n!} \le $

$1 + f(1) + f(2) + ...... + f(n) \le$

$1+F(n)$

where $F(n)$ is something bounded that we can manipulate.

$f(k) = \frac 1{2^{k-1}}$ and $F(n) = 1+ \frac 11+ \frac 12 + \frac 14 + ..... + \frac 1{2^{n-}}$ are good choices because $F(n) = 1+ \frac 11+ \frac 12 + \frac 14 + ..... + \frac 1{2^{n-1}}= 3-\frac 1{2^{n}}<3$ is a *really* easy calculation to make and prove, and proving that $\frac 1{n!} =\frac 1{2*3*4*5*....*n} \le \frac 1{2*2*2*.....*}=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}$ is equally easy.

If we can find find some *other* $f(k)$ and $F(n)$ and $K$ so that $\frac 1{n!} \le f(n)$ and that $1 + \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = 1+ F(n) \le K$ we are free to use those but... powers of $2$ these choices are so *easy*.

Question 2:

$\le$ is weaker than $<$ and a stronger statement always implies a weaker statement.

$n! > 2^{n-1} \implies \frac 1{n!} < \frac 1{2^{n-1}} \implies \frac 1{n!} \le \frac 1{2^{n-1}}$.

That certainly isn't *false*.

But as to *why* we used $\le$ rather than $<$..... well, for the case when $n =1$ and $\frac 1{n!} = \frac 1{2^{n-1}}$.  That's all.  It's a one time exception.

Question 3:

It's just a lower bound.  If $n = 1$ then $x_1 = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^1 \frac 1{k!} = 1+ \frac 1{1!} = 2$.

That's all.

Question 4:

It is a well known equality that for any $q\ne 1$ that $1 + q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1} = \frac {1-q^n}{1-q} = \frac {q^n -1}{q-1}$

$(1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1})(1-q)=$

$(1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}) - q(1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1})=$

$(1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}) - (q + q^2 + q^3 + ..... + q^{n})= $

$(1 + \underbrace{q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}}) -(\underbrace{q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}} + q^n) =$

$1-q^n$.

So if $(1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1})(1-q) = 1-q^n$ then  $\frac {1-q^n}{1-q} = (1+q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1})$

"Is this a known thing, that the order of subracting isn't important for two fractions to be equal, as long as both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction are both <0 or >0"

Yes.  It *is* a known thing:  $\frac {a-b}{c-d} = \frac {a-b}{c-d}\frac {-1}{-1} = \frac {-(a-b)}{-(c-d)} = \frac {b-a}{d-c}$.

Question 5:

If $\color{green}{1 + q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}} = \color{green}{\frac {q^n -1}{q-1}}$ then

$\color{red}1 + \color{green}{1 + q + q^2 + ..... + q^{n-1}} = \color{red}1 +\color{green}{\frac {q^n -1}{q-1}}$

And notice back in 1.3 we had

$x_n = \color{red}1 + \color{green}{1 + \frac 12 + \frac 1{4} + .... + \frac 1{2^{n-1}}}$

....

Maybe this is all to complicated.

I'd do it.

$1 + \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} + \frac 1{3!} + \frac 1{4!}+ ....... + \frac 1{n!} =$

$(1 + 1) + \frac 1{2} + \frac 1{2*3} + \frac 1{2*3*4} + ..... + \frac 1{2*3*4*....n}< $

$2 + \frac 1{2} + \frac 1{2*2} + \frac 1{2*2*2} + .... + \frac 1{2*2*2*....*2} =$

$2 + (\frac 12 + \frac 1{4} + \frac 1{8} + ...... + \frac 1{2^{n-1}})$.

Then I'd make one of my flying leaps that every one knows the things I used to know as a kid that $\frac 12 + \frac 1{4} + \frac 1{8} + ...... + \frac 1{2^{n-1}} = 1-\frac 1{2^n} < 1$ because *everyone* has heard of the jumping flea paradox so *everyone* has seen this in kindergarten, haven't they?  No? .... Well, each time we add only *half* of what we need to get to $1$ so we never add enough to get to one so the sum has to be less than $1$, right?  Because we never add enough to get to $1$.

So $2 + (\frac 12 + \frac 1{4} + \frac 1{8} + ...... + \frac 1{2^{n-1}})< 2 + 1=3$

That really is *all* this proof is saying.

The key issue is noting that $2*3*4*...... *n \le 2*2*2*2*....*2$.  Everything else just falls into place.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

1. $2^{n-1}$ is a good choice because of the series in (1.3)
2. I think that it is a typo. The correct is $n!\geq 2^{n-1}$, since for $n=1$, the equality holds. And for all the values, we know that $n!>2^{n-1}$. It is a classical exercise in Analysis (maybe Calculus too?) that the function $x!$ grows faster than $x^a$ for any real value of $a$. Try it :)
3. Remember that $x_n=1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}$. For $n=1, x_1=2$, and for all other values for $n$, $x_n>2$. That's way $x_n\geq 2.$
4. (a) In general,

$$a+ar+\cdots+ar^{n-1}=a\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}. $$

There is several ways of proving this. For example, let $S_n=a+ar+\dots ar^n.$ Now evaluate $S_n-S_{n-1}$, and see what you got.

(b) Just multiply the numerator and the denominator by $(-1)$

5. It comes from "nowhere". It is the beginning of a new equation. It just uses the inequality in (1.4)
6. I don't know anyone :c

Comment: Many thanks, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'll try answer step by step:

1. $(1.1)$ is not true for $n=1$.
2. To obtain $(1.2)$ from $(1.1)$ use $\frac{1}{a} <\frac{1}{b}\Leftrightarrow b<a$ for non negative numbers.
3. For left side of $(1.3)$ we have that $x_1$ already contain 2, for right use $(1.2)$
4. There is formula for sum for first members of [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)
5. It is first member of $x_n$
6. Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis-(1976) from page 63 have similar reasonings.

Comment: "For left side of (1.3) we have that x1 already contain 2", I see. But what are we showing with explicating that? I don't see how that explication is used in the proof. Many thanks for your answer

Comment: You are right. In proof we do not use it. I only answer to your question. For proof is enough boundary from right, because, of increasing.

Comment: That's it, got it!

Comment: I just checked the proof in Rudin, it is very similar. Many thanks for the effort